# Soapstone Seal Translation

Tags: translation, characters, seal

[image]Can anyone give me any information about this old stamp?  possibly translate the symbols?  Very worn carved soapstone in tortoise shell case with red waxy ink.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Oh wow - comes out as Matsubara Yuki,  Japanese ?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

My interpretation:

> 肇　松
>
> 吉　原

The guess of「肇」is based on [this variant](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/jinwen?kaiOrder=64260) of「肁」.

> <kbd>[西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou)
> [金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
> [image]
> 耳尊
> [集成6007](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=6007&jgwfl=)</kbd>
> <kbd>[隸定](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/%E9%9A%B6%E5%AE%9A)
> [image]</kbd>

Together, this makes a Japanese name 松原肇吉 (something like *Matsubara Tadayoshi*).

<sub>You should post this on https://japanese.stackexchange.com to doublecheck.</sub>

Comment: Once again, very helpful thank you !  I will try your suggestion.